# Model for Script/language detection from images

Tags: python, computer-vision, detection

Are there any language/script detection models available apart from Tesseract OCR.

I know Tesseract OCR does this job with Image to osd(Orientation and Script detection) feature. Are there any models available which has this kind of feature to detect the script from the given image

I have tried Tesseract OCR and also few other resources like https://github.com/mikekestemont/DeepScript - DeepScript which are 7 years old.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for open-source I am afraid there aren't any other clear solutions to the problem. I checked some projects dedicated to solving this problem, however, they seem to be using the Tesseract API only in the background.

As for paid applications and API services, AWS *textract* does not give script information as per the documentation. Its not mentioned anywhere if they include the script type in the metadata of the Block object that is returned. I am not sure about the solutions provided by Google as I have not used it.